# Reactjs create a new tab instead of a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window

I am trying to create a new window using javascript but it create a new tab instead of a new window

```
    const raiseInvoiceClicked = () => {
        let params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,
width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1000`;

        const newWindow = window.open("http://localhost:3000", '_blank', "height=200,width=200", 'noopener,noreferrer')
        if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f you want to create a new tab in React.js when a user clicks a link or a button instead of opening a new window, you can achieve this by using the target="_blank" attribute in the link or by programmatically opening a new tab using JavaScript. Here are both approaches:

Using target="_blank" in a Link:

    const raiseInvoiceClicked = () => {
  const windowFeatures = "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=200,height=200,left=-1000,top=-1000";

  const newWindow = window.open("http://localhost:3000", "_blank", windowFeatures);

  if (newWindow) {
    newWindow.opener = null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const secondScreen = window.open("https://www.google.com",'','width=200px,height=200px');
```

will open google in new window and size will be 200x200